# Rename Root folder directory - I've managed to rename folder structure to my name by mistake

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, kali-linux

Using Kali Linux and somehow managed to rename a folder in the structure:

root:/bin/bash/**myName**

- So my question is how can I rename the **myName** folder? as I would like to set up a new user profile with my name, which, currently would be confusing as my name is also used in the root user pathway.

Id like to have the new pathway reading: 
root:/bin/bash/root Or rootuser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: This is very unclear what you want to do. `/bin/bash` is the path of `bash` not a folder. try `ls -ls /bin/bash`  you'll see that it is a binary file not a folder

Answer (score 1):

The [only user in Kali Linux](https://itsfoss.com/kali-linux-review/) is *root*; you can't create a new user.

> ...on a default Kali Linux system, the only installed user is root and
>   you have to work under that identity all the time. You have to
>   understand that being root means there is basically no permissions
>   checks on your machine. You can do everything you want. And even
>   things you don’t want.